# Keras Lambda layer has no output tensor shape, error when compiling model

Tags: python, lambda, machine-learning, keras, autoencoder

I'm trying to build a character-level auto-encoder for text sequences using Keras. When I compile the model, I get an error concerning the shapes of the tensors as you can see bellow. I printed out the layers specifications to check, if the tensor shapes match up and I found that the problem is probably with the last Lambda layer not having an *Output Tensor Shape* specified correctly, but I can't figure out why not or how to specify it and didn't find anything about it in the documentation of Keras or on Google.

Below the error output is also the part of the code, where I define my model. The whole script for clarification, if needed, is here: [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/gDvyZQk6).

### Error and layer output

(Mind mainly the last layer.)

```
0        <keras.engine.topology.InputLayer object at 0x7f5d290eb588> Input shape (None, 80) Output shape (None, 80)
1        <keras.layers.core.Lambda object at 0x7f5d35f25a20> Input shape (None, 80) Output shape (None, 80, 99)
2        <keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x7f5d2dda52e8> Input shape (None, 80, 99) Output shape (None, 80, 256)
3        <keras.layers.core.Dropout object at 0x7f5d25004da0> Input shape (None, 80, 256) Output shape (None, 80, 256)
4        <keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x7f5d2501ac18> Input shape (None, 80, 256) Output shape (None, 80, 128)
5        <keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x7f5d24dc6cc0> Input shape (None, 80, 128) Output shape (None, 80, 64)
6        <keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x7f5d24de1fd0> Input shape (None, 80, 64) Output shape (None, 80, 128)
7        <keras.layers.core.Dropout object at 0x7f5d24df4a20> Input shape (None, 80, 128) Output shape (None, 80, 128)
8        <keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x7f5d24dfeb38> Input shape (None, 80, 128) Output shape (None, 80, 256)
9        <keras.layers.core.Lambda object at 0x7f5d24da6a20> Input shape (None, 80, 256) Output shape (None, 80)
----------------
0        Input Tensor("input_1:0", shape=(?, 80), dtype=int64) Output Tensor("input_1:0", shape=(?, 80), dtype=int64)
1        Input Tensor("input_1:0", shape=(?, 80), dtype=int64) Output Tensor("ToFloat:0", shape=(?, 80, 99), dtype=float32)
2        Input Tensor("ToFloat:0", shape=(?, 80, 99), dtype=float32) Output Tensor("Relu:0", shape=(?, 80, 256), dtype=float32)
3        Input Tensor("Relu:0", shape=(?, 80, 256), dtype=float32) Output Tensor("cond/Merge:0", shape=(?, 80, 256), dtype=float32)
4        Input Tensor("cond/Merge:0", shape=(?, 80, 256), dtype=float32) Output Tensor("Relu_1:0", shape=(?, 80, 128), dtype=float32)
5        Input Tensor("Relu_1:0", shape=(?, 80, 128), dtype=float32) Output Tensor("Relu_2:0", shape=(?, 80, 64), dtype=float32)
6        Input Tensor("Relu_2:0", shape=(?, 80, 64), dtype=float32) Output Tensor("Relu_3:0", shape=(?, 80, 128), dtype=float32)
7        Input Tensor("Relu_3:0", shape=(?, 80, 128), dtype=float32) Output Tensor("cond_1/Merge:0", shape=(?, 80, 128), dtype=float32)
8        Input Tensor("cond_1/Merge:0", shape=(?, 80, 128), dtype=float32) Output Tensor("truediv:0", shape=(?, 80, 256), dtype=float32)
9        Input Tensor("truediv:0", shape=(?, 80, 256), dtype=float32) Output Tensor("ToFloat_1:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)
----------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py", line 578, in merge_with
    self.assert_same_rank(other)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py", line 624, in assert_same_rank
    "Shapes %s and %s must have the same rank" % (self, other))
ValueError: Shapes (?, ?) and () must have the same rank

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_impl.py", line 153, in sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits
    labels.get_shape().merge_with(logits.get_shape())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py", line 585, in merge_with
    (self, other))
ValueError: Shapes (?, ?) and () are not compatible

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lstm.py", line 97, in <module>
    autoencoder.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 667, in compile
    sample_weight, mask)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 318, in weighted
    score_array = fn(y_true, y_pred)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/keras/objectives.py", line 45, in binary_crossentropy
    return K.mean(K.binary_crossentropy(y_pred, y_true), axis=-1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2449, in binary_crossentropy
    logits=output)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_impl.py", line 156, in sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits
    % (logits.get_shape(), labels.get_shape()))
ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape (() vs (?, ?))
```

## Code

I've built my model using this code:

```
def binarize(x, sz):
    return tf.to_float(tf.one_hot(x, sz, on_value=1, off_value=0, axis=-1))


def binarize_outputshape(in_shape):
    return in_shape[0], in_shape[1], len(chars)


def debinarize(x):
    return tf.to_float(np.argmax(x))  # get the character with most probability


def debinarize_outputshape(in_shape):
    return in_shape[0], in_shape[1]

input_sentence = Input(shape=(max_title_len,), dtype='int64')
# make one-hot vectors out of sentences
one_hot = Lambda(binarize, output_shape=binarize_outputshape, arguments={'sz': len(chars)})(input_sentence)

# shape: max_title_len * chars = 80 * 55 = 4400
encoder = Dense(256, activation='relu')(one_hot)
encoder = Dropout(0.1)(encoder)
encoder = Dense(128, activation='relu')(encoder)

encoder = Dense(64, activation='relu')(encoder)

decoder = Dense(128, activation='relu')(encoder)
encoder = Dropout(0.1)(encoder)
decoder = Dense(256, activation='softmax')(decoder)
# transform back from one-hot vectors
decoder = Lambda(debinarize, output_shape=debinarize_outputshape)(decoder)

autoencoder = Model(input=input_sentence, output=decoder)
```

Firstly, I input a text sequence of maximum 80 chars, the Lambda layer transforms each character to a one-hot vector. At the end, I would like to transform the one-hot vectors back, while taking only the maximum as the decoded character.

## Question

1. Am I missing something in the model construction code?
2. How can I make the Lambda layer know the output tensor shape?

## Edit

As [Nassim Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7137636/nassim-ben) pointed out, the problem was with the function *debinarize*. After changing it to:

```
def debinarize(x):
    return tf.to_float(tf.argmax(x, axis=0))
```

at least some kind of value was set to the Output tensor's shape. Though the value is a bit weird, because it is **(80, 256)** and differs from the output shape **(None, 80)**. All the other output tensor shapes and output shapes match up correspondingly (I suppose the '?' and None mean the same more or less...). More specifically, the Lambda layer now looks like this:

```
 <keras.layers.core.Lambda object at 0x7fafcc5a59b0> Input shape (None, 80, 256) Output shape (None, 80)
...
...
Input Tensor("truediv:0", shape=(?, 80, 256), dtype=float32) Output Tensor("ToFloat_1:0", shape=(80, 256), dtype=float32)
```

Problem is, I would like output tensor shape to be (?, 80) as is the first layer's input. I did not change any other code than the *argmax*.

The error given is now:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lstm.py", line 122, in <module>
    callbacks=[earlystop_cb, check_cb, keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir='/tmp/autoencoder')])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1168, in fit
    self._make_train_function()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 760, in _make_train_function
    self.total_loss)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/keras/optimizers.py", line 433, in get_updates
    m_t = (self.beta_1 * m) + (1. - self.beta_1) * g
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 883, in binary_op_wrapper
    y = ops.convert_to_tensor(y, dtype=x.dtype.base_dtype, name="y")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 651, in convert_to_tensor
    as_ref=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 716, in internal_convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 176, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
    return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 165, in constant
    tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 360, in make_tensor_proto
    raise ValueError("None values not supported.")
ValueError: None values not supported.
```

Comment: Why are you passing a function `binarize_outputshape` intead of actual shape output?

Comment: It's just convenience really. I'm in the phase of creating the model, so I often change the layer dimensions and with the function I don't have to change as many constants...also I saw it somewhere and just stuck with this way of doing it :).

Comment: But you are passing a function in a place where you should pass a tuple. Shouldn't it be a function call instead of a function?

Comment: a function is correct for the output_shape

Comment: As you see here: https://keras.io/layers/core/#lambda it can also be a function returning a tuple :)

Comment: Yes. I forgot about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it comes from using a numpy function on a tensor.
Try using tf argmax function (I think the axis you want to reduce is 1, not sure)

```
def debinarize(x):
    return tf.to_float(tf.argmax(x,axis=2))  # get the character with most probability
```

Does this work?

Comment: Thanks, this did actually get rid of the error (the axis was 0) and set the output tensor shape to a value! Though it isn't the value I would expect (Input Tensor("truediv:0", shape=(?, 80, 256), dtype=float32) Output Tensor("ToFloat_1:0", **shape=(80, 256)**, dtype=float32))). I would like it to be the same as the first layer (None, 80).

Comment: Are you sure that you are using : def debinarize_outputshape(in_shape):
    return in_shape[0], in_shape[1]  ? this function should output (?,80) by its definition if the input was (?,80,256). Can you edit your question with more info?

Comment: I edited it :). I printed out the argument of debinarize_outputshape and it is as you say (?, 80, 256) so the function does return (?, 80) and I am definitely calling the correct one. No idea  what the issue is.

Comment: can you do print(input_shape) in your debiniarize_outputshape function? and copy the output here :)

Comment: and try with axis = 1 too please

Comment: Sure. With 0: (None, 80, 256). With 1: (None, 80, 256) and the output tensor shape changed to (?, 256).

Comment: Alright, that's what I thought, axis = 2 is your solution. The tensor is 3D, it takes into account the batch dimension. You want to crunch the 2nd axis, to take the arg max between the 256 values of every 80 tensors.

Comment: Yes! That was it. Thank you. The shapes are now perfect :). Though the other error still persists :D. I will have to look into that a bit more. Your help was very much appreciated!

Comment: Yep, coming from one of your callbacks